# Apply hover overlay to Woocommerce archive listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a hover style to the woocommerce category images on the product page.

I've created the following code, which is working, however it's pretty poor as the overlays 'stick on' or overlay on each other, don't toggle properly etc. It seems the code isn't running quick enough

```
$('a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').css({
        position: 'relative'
    });
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    $("<table id='overlay'><tbody><tr><td>" + 'SHOP NOW >' + "</td></tr></tbody></table>").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0px",
        "left": "0px",
        "width": img.width(),
        "height": img.height(),
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
        "z-index": "10000",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "text-align": "center",
        "color": "#fff",
        "font-size": "1rem",
        "cursor": "pointer"
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

I would like to have this in CSS, however I cannot account for the variable image size and content of the overlay.

Comment: Why are using a `table` for the overlay when you can use a `div`. Are there any particular reason for it?

Comment: Positions the text in the centre nice and easily.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the work you have done so far. I bet you can do all you want without an extra markup.

Comment: Hi Dan, that JS is basically everything.

Comment: Does the text 'Shop Now' change at any time.

Comment: No, I've tried to find a place in the woocommerce template or a hook where I can place this as static HTML however I've been unsuccessful, hence using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to do it in JavaScript `position: absolute` elements if set `top` `left` `bottom` `right` to zero takes the full width and height of their relative parents dynamic in this case. You dont even need an extra `div` for it when you can make use of pseudo elements.

Overlay using pure CSS affects the performance much less when compared to the script.

```css
ul.test {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.test li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.test li a img {
  display: block;
}

ul.test li:before {
  content: 'SHOP NOW';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*To align the content*/
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.test li:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img src="https://www.qvb.com.au/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_sample-200x200.png" alt=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img src="http://www.omega4agents.com/wp-content/uploads/Sample-Gallery-1-200x300.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/crop/200x400/http://sample.li/eiffel.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```